# Pull an array based on one criteria in two columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to be able to pull all values from column A that meet one criteria specified (preferably from another cell) and search columns B and C. For example, if I were to select Grass in the formula, the results would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in E3:

```
=Filter(A1:A,(B1:B=G1)+(C1:C=G1)>=1)
```

a1:a - is column you want to see

b1:b=g1 and c1:c=g1 these are logic tests that return 1 when true

So when one or more columns contain content of G1 (grass) then condition is met and content of cell from column A is displayed.